# iOS 4 issues with event.layerX and event.layerY on touchstart

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, ios4

This code:

```
$(doc).on('touchstart touchend', function(ev){
    var or = ev.originalEvent;
    console.log('y: '+or.layerY+' x '+or.layerX);
});
```

Is displaying the coordinates of the position where I tap on in iOS 5, but in iOS 4 is giving 0 for both coordinates. `doc` is a variable that contains the `contentDocument` of an iframe and I'm using jQuery 1.7.1. Any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the properties `ev.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX` and `ev.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY`. Don't know why `layerX` and `layerY` are not working properly, but the other ones seems to make the trick

Comment: "pageX" is not the best one, just in case the scroll move while the touch occurs, for whatever reason. "clientX" or "screenX" might be better.